Graphing Multiple Replicates of a randomly generated parameter in an ODE model
I'm pretty new to this and I'm trying to figure out how I can graph multiple results of a randomly generated number between (0:0.04) and I have it graphed but I'm so confused as to why the blue graph lines are angling back towards the initial start of the graph? I was expecting it to look more fan-like and not like it should be looping back towards the beginning?
library(deSolve)  

sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
    dB <- -M*B_cells - beta*Cb*B_cells - beta_2*Ct*B_cells + (g1*(Cb+Ct)/(g2+(Cb+Ct))) 
    dCb <- M*B_cells + beta*Cb*B_cells + beta_2*Ct*B_cells - alpha*Cb
    dT <- -nu_A*Cb*T_cells - nu_b*Ct*T_cells + (h1*(Cb+Ct)/(h2+(Cb+Ct)))
    dAt <- nu_A*Cb*T_cells + nu_b*Ct*T_cells - beta_2*Ct*At - beta*Cb*At
    dLt <- theta*(beta_2*Ct*At + beta*Cb*At)
    dCt <- (1-theta)*(beta_2*Ct*At + beta*Cb*At) - alpha_2*Ct
    dZ <- mu*Lt
    df <- -nu_F*Lt*f
    dIf <- nu_F*Lt*f
    return(list(c(dB, dCb, dT, dAt, dLt, dCt, dZ, df,dIf)))
  })
} 
mu_vec <- runif(5, min=0, max = 0.04)
res <- vector(length(mu_vec), mode = "list")
for (k in seq_along(mu_vec)) {
  res[[k]] <- ode(y = initial_values, times = time_values,
                  func = sir_equations, parms= c(mu=mu_vec[k],
                                                 M=0.05,
                                                 beta = 4.819e-4,
                                                 beta_2 =5e-4,
                                                 nu_A = 0.005,
                                                 nu_b = 0.01,
                                                 nu_F = 0.7,
                                                 alpha = 0.015,
                                                 alpha_2 = 0.010,
                                                 theta = 0.5,
                                                 g1 = 0.05,
                                                 g2 =0.001,
                                                 h1 = 0,
                                                 h2 = 10))
}  

names(res) <- mu_vec
dd <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(res, as.data.frame), .id= "mu")

dd$mu <- as.numeric(dd$mu)

initial_values <- c( 
  B_cells = 50  
  , Cb = 0 
  , T_cells=50 
  , At = 0
  , Lt = 0
  , Ct = 0
  , Z = 0
  , f =5 
  , If =0
  
)  


time_values <- seq(0,300) # hours


with(dd, {
  plot(x=time, y=B_cells, col="black", type="l", ylim= c(0,100),  xlab="Time (Hours)", ylab="Population density", main="Marek's Model")          #Plot the data for S over time
  lines(time, T_cells, col="red")  
  lines(time, Cb, col= "green")                                  #Add a line for I over time
  lines(time, At, col="blue")
  lines(time,Lt, col="purple" ) 
  lines(time,Ct, col="yellow" )  
  lines(time, Z, col= "lightblue") 
  lines(time, f, col="aquamarine") 
  lines(time,If, col="pink" ) 
})


I would greatly appreciate anyones input! Thanks so much!
Graph with weird lines
I have tried using the replicate function instead to see if maybe I should try another way but I got confused with how to implement the random values for mu and replicate function doesn't seem to capture what I want to do..

The light blue lines are the Z variable. Besides of this, it is unclear how the desired plot should look like, as it is attempted to plot all scenarios (random mu) and all states together. I would recommend to make different plots, either all states per scenario or all scenarios per state variable.
The following shows a way with ggplot, that supports a compact specification of multiple plots. It requires that the data are in "long format", that is possible with pivot_longer from the tidyr package.
An additional improvement is to define a function for a single simulation, that can then be called with lapply, but the original version with the for-loop can also be made working.
The final two lines show then two ways to plot the results.
library(deSolve)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
    dB <- -M*B_cells - beta*Cb*B_cells - beta_2*Ct*B_cells + (g1*(Cb+Ct)/(g2+(Cb+Ct)))
    dCb <- M*B_cells + beta*Cb*B_cells + beta_2*Ct*B_cells - alpha*Cb
    dT <- -nu_A*Cb*T_cells - nu_b*Ct*T_cells + (h1*(Cb+Ct)/(h2+(Cb+Ct)))
    dAt <- nu_A*Cb*T_cells + nu_b*Ct*T_cells - beta_2*Ct*At - beta*Cb*At
    dLt <- theta*(beta_2*Ct*At + beta*Cb*At)
    dCt <- (1-theta)*(beta_2*Ct*At + beta*Cb*At) - alpha_2*Ct
    dZ <- mu*Lt
    df <- -nu_F*Lt*f
    dIf <- nu_F*Lt*f
    return(list(c(dB, dCb, dT, dAt, dLt, dCt, dZ, df, dIf)))
  })
}

initial_values <- c(B_cells = 50, Cb = 0, T_cells=50,
                    At = 0, Lt = 0, Ct = 0, Z = 0, f = 5, If =0)


time_values <- seq(0,300) # hours

## define the vector outside of a loop or lapply
parms <- c(mu=NA, M=0.05, beta = 4.819e-4, beta_2 =5e-4, nu_A = 0.005,
           nu_b = 0.01, nu_F = 0.7, alpha = 0.015, alpha_2 = 0.010, theta = 0.5,
           g1 = 0.05, g2 =0.001, h1 = 0, h2 = 10)

## random parameter, optionally round it to 4 digits, to make the plot nicer
mu_vec <- round(runif(5, min=0, max = 0.04), 4)

## function to run a single scenario
run_scenario <- function(mu) {
  parms["mu"] <- mu
  out <- ode(y = initial_values, times = time_values, func = sir_equations, parms=parms)
  as.data.frame(cbind(mu, out))
}

## run all scenarios with lapply
## a for-loop would also be possible, but lapply is more compact and returns
## automatically a list
res <- lapply(mu_vec, run_scenario)

## combine all scenarios in a data frame and then make a long table, that
## is compatible with ggplot
## mu must be converted to a factor or character
## so that it can be used for color and facet_wrap
dd <- dplyr::bind_rows(res) |>
  pivot_longer(cols= -c(mu, time)) |>
  mutate(mu=factor(mu))

## one plot per scenario, all states together
ggplot(dd, aes(time, value, color=name)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~mu)

## one plot per state, all scenarios together
ggplot(dd, aes(time, value, color=mu)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~name)



